# GAE Datastore write operations dalay

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a DB that maintain a list of calls. Every week I have to import an excel file or a json object to make sure that the  list of calls data is in sync with another db, which has a different format (I have to do some interpretations on the data I get from the xls)

Anyhow, I made a function that do all the import, but I noticed that each time I run it I get different results.

After some investigation, what I notice is that if I do lots of put() in sequence there is a lag between the end of the put and when the data is available in the datastore so queries sometimes return different values.

I fixed it adding a delay

```
time.sleep(1)
```

But I think there should be a way to just wait until datastore is stable and not a fixed amount of time. I tried to find it but had no luck.

Any help?

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 2):

This is an often repeated question - though other question at first may not seem the same.

If you are using the datastore you MUST read up on "Eventual consistency"

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/

In my opinion the docs for appengine and the datastore should probably lead off with "If you haven't read about eventual consistency, please do so now!" in really big type ;-)

Comment: ...and, tl;dr, use a sync-forcing operation such as `get` on a key to force strong consistency, after you're done w/all your `put`s and before you query back to check.  Also consider (for speed) multi_put_async and waiting on all the futures before said sync-forcing.